# Dropdown list with data in tree view format for SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the below data structer(sample data)

```
Path
----
a\a.a
a
a\a.b\
a\a.a\a.a.a
b
a\a.a\a.a.b
b.a
a\a.b\a.b.a
b\b.a\b.a.a
c
b\b.b
a\a.a\a.a.c
a\a.a\a.a.a
a\a.b\a.b.a
b\b.a\b.a.a
```

I need to have these values in dropdown list in below format with mulitselect option in SSRS Report. These values will 
act as input to the next linked ssrs report.

```
  [Checkbox] a
    [Checkbox] a.a
        [Checkbox] a.a.a
        [Checkbox] a.a.b
        [Checkbox] a.a.c
  [Checkbox] b
    [Checkbox] b.a
        [Checkbox] b.a.a
    [Checkbox] b.b
  [Checkbox] c
```

Could someone help on this?

If need more clarification, pls let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? As it stands, there is no particular question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a heirarchy and need recursion.  But I am not certain so I will assume that is the case.  I would suggest two things:

1. Instead of giving the heirarchy element can you instead use the ID and ParentID creating the heirarchy?  If so SSRS can do recursion for you.  You merely set up a 'Row Group' then under that group's 'properties' go to 'Adanced' and set the ParentID to be the 'Recursive Parent'.
2. If you want an indent that is a little more syntactical sugar in SSRS.  In the cell that relates to the beginning of the Group set the 'Padding' property to something like:

   ```
   =CStr(2 + (Level()*10)) + "pt", 2pt, 2pt, 2pt
   ```

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

I think you have the structure complete so just go to the query designer and add the dimension as a parameter and select it as a parameter.

[image: query designer]

[image: preview]